# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of null for stripe payment

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, stripe-payments

I am integrating stripe payments into my app.  I switched out the Stripe default "Pay with Card" button for one I customized.  After doing this, the test mode successfully pops-up and I can enter the test credentials. However, when I submit the test payment, and it is approved, it just stays on the same pin page rather than going to the charges page that I created for it.

Note: the app would transition just fine from stripe payment to the charges create.html.erb page up until I replaced the default stripe payment button with my new customized button.

Also, looking at developer tools I do note that it reads when I submit test payment:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of null
```

I think this is referring to my code below where I submit the chargeForm.

Anyone encounter this issue before or know I can fix this?  Many thanks!

app/views/pins/_details.html.erb

```
        <%= form_tag charges_path, id: 'chargesForm' do %>
          <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
          <%= hidden_field_tag 'stripeToken' %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag 'stripeEmail' %>  
          <button id="btn-buy" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>   I want this!</button>

          <script>
          var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
            key: '<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>',
            token: function(token, arg) {
              document.getElementById("stripeToken").value = token.id;
              document.getElementById("stripeEmail").value = token.email;
              document.getElementById("chargeForm").submit();
            }
          });
           document.getElementById('btn-buy').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            handler.open({
              name: 'OMG! <%= @pin.manufacturer %>',
              description: '<%= @pin.description %>',
              amount: 1000
          });
          e.preventDefault();
         })
        </script>
      <% end %>
```

app/controllers/charges_controller.rb

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController

def create
  # Amount in cents
  @amount = 500

  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :email => params[:stripeEmail],
    :card  => params[:stripeToken]
  )

  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :customer    => customer.id,
    :amount      => @amount,
    :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
    :currency    => 'usd'
  )

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      redirect_to charges_path
   end

end
```

app/views/charges/create.html.erb

```
You bought some Awesome stuff!
```

app/config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :pins
  resources :charges

  devise_for :users
  root "pins#index"
  get "about" => "pages#about" #creates about_path
  get "contact" => "pages#contact" #creates contact_path
  get "auction" => "pages#auction" #creates auction_path
  get "terms" => "pages#terms" #creates terms_path
  post 'send_mail', to: 'contact#send_mail'
  get 'contact', to: 'contact#show'

 scope 'pins', controller: :pins do
    scope '/:id' do
     post 'bid', to: :bid
    end
 end

  scope 'admin', controller: :admin do
    scope 'pins' do
      get '/:pin_id', to: :pin
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Javascript code reads

```
document.getElementById("chargeForm").submit();
```

while your form name is `chargesForm`

```
<%= form_tag charges_path, id: 'chargesForm' do %>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when in a page I had many forms for a delete action in a table. I was able to figure why I keep getting this error when I found out that the quotes(single or double quotes) must appear in the

```
  document.getElementById("whatever id keep quotes ").submit();
```

and make sure it matches the form id.

e.g.

```
  document.getElementById("'delform'.$key ").submit();

  <form id="delform.$key" action="" ></form>
```